# xml woes: struggling getting data with elementree, xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

Having trouble figuring out how to parse `xml` in `etree` with and without `xpath`.

I am trying to get all instances of an element as a record, with put each instance's subfields into a dictionary. Ultimately, I want the field data into a Pandas `DataFrame` with the val name attributes as column headers.

Below, each "map" is a record.

Sample `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response xmlns="a url">
    <fn>
        <list>
        <map>
        <val name="COUNT">0</val>
        <val name="CATEGORY">AA</val>
        <val name="AVERAGE">48.064133</val>
        <val name="RANKING">4</val>
        <val name="NAME">PORTER</val>
        <val name="INDUSTRY_TAG">DESIGN</val>
        </map>
        <map>
        <val name="COUNT">3</val>
        <val name="CATEGORY">BA</val>
        <val name="AVERAGE">77.33</val>
        <val name="RANKING">27</val>
        <val name="NAME">DANIELS</val>
        <val name="INDUSTRY_TAG">INTERACTIVE</val>
        </map>
        <map>
        <val name="COUNT">8</val>
        <val name="CATEGORY">BB</val>
        <val name="AVERAGE">102.85</val>
        <val name="RANKING">15</val>
        <val name="NAME">SWEETWATER</val>
        <val name="INDUSTRY_TAG">GRAPHIC</val>
        </map>
        </list>
    </fn>
</response>
```

The `xml` comes from an api. "response" is the variable the api call has been assigned to. The code below generates one continuous list of the "val" variables.

```
root = etree.fromstring(response.content)
for node in root.findall('.//*/*[@name]')
    print(node.text)
```

I have tried messing around with `xpath` to try to get the "map" level, but that isn't working.

I have played around with `xpath` statements based on [this guide on xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) and [these examples](https://gist.github.com/IanHopkinson/ad45831a2fb73f537a79) but only the following seems to find anything, but it's the same single list as above:

```
for node in root.xpath('//*[@name]'):
    print(node.text)
```

I've tried an absolute path -- `root.xpath('response/fn/list/map')`, but that doesn't seem to work. I tried `root.xpath('//val')` because I thought that would get me all of the "val" variables, but that hasn't worked. If I enter `root.xpath('//*')` I get that list of "val" values.

Clearly I am not grokking something fundamental and would appreciate being put on the path to wisdom.

Thanks

Comment: For the absolute path it would have to be `root.find_element_by_xpath("response/fn/list/map[1]")` or `root.find_element_by_xpath("//map[1]")`

Comment: @JeanRostan: The essential reason his XPath is failing is due to neglecting XML namespaces.  This has been asked and answered many times over, thus the duplicate closure; there's nothing new here.

Comment: @kjhughes you're right, sorry for the disturbance, I was only thinking of doing it with elemttree and not xpath...

Comment: Sorry for the poorly-worded question and thanks to the person who tracked me down to share the code to help me get the values from my xml.